# How to use a verb

Tags: verbs

Could i say " the president would like to retract the siege" or it would be better to replace retract with draw back

Comment: I think you're probably wanting ***lift** the siege,* which is certainly an unusual verb. It appears to be [sense 4 in Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lift). Is that what you want? To withdraw all the forces laying siege? (Note: *lay* as in "place, position, put"; *lift* as in "take away from having put down")

Comment: I suggest "discontinue/abandon the siege"